# History with bash file

Tags: bash, command-history

I'm running a bash file to obtain data on what system processes are running (i.e netstat, syslog, arp etc). All's going well except for the history.
I'm trying to save the history to a text file with

```
cp ~/. bash_history $path/filename.txt
```

Unfortunately this doesn't give me the complete history. If manually input the command

```
history > /media/root/usb/filename
```

I get a completely different result.
My aim is to automate the whole process under the one bash file, is there a way of doing this. Also i'd ideally like the date and time with the history.

Comment: are you actually typing `cp ~/. bash_history $path/filename.txt` or `cp ~/.bash_history $path/filename.txt`   I'm not seeing a very big difference between my `.bash_history` and `history`

Comment: One thing I believe may be the issue is it appears `history` doesn't write to `.bash_history` until you log out.  So `.bash_history` should include everything except your current session, where `history` would include everything.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) clarify the command you use. The one you show would give you an error. ii) Explain what's missing. Which command in the history don't you see? Is it only the latest ones from your current shell (open terminal)? iii) What format do you want the time and date to be? Show us an example of your expected output.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `history -a; cp ~/.bash_history $path/filename.txt` to ensure that your bash_history is written to just before you perform the copy.

Comment: The bash in-memory history is flushed to the history file at the end of the shell session, by default. You would have to manually flush the history before copying the file. The bash manual contains all relevant information.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your replies. I'm not typing cp ~/. bash_history $path/filename

Comment: I'm trying to run the history command as part of a single process to gather as much detail as possible about the the Linux computer before I switch it off and lose volatile data

Comment: Please ***[edit]*** your question to clarify as requested. Comments are easy to miss and hard to read.

Answer (score 4):

As @Jesse_b commented, `.bash_history` contains the history of all your previous shell sessions except the current one, which can be examined via the `history`command. So you'll have first to flush the current history via

```
history -a
```

and then you can copy it to another file:

```
cp ~/.bash_history $path/filename.txt
```

To prepend each history entry with a timestamp, set the $HISTTIMEFORMAT variable, e.g.

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T: "
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I ran history -a to flush the current history and then ran my bash file which included cp ~/.bash_history $path/filename.txt and it did include the most up to date history. Is there a way to automate this process as part of my bash file rather than having to type history -a

Comment: This process is already automated when you log out. Is there another `action` you would like to `initiate` this process?

Answer (score 1):

To get date and the time in your history , run the following commands:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
echo 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
history
```

[How to see time stamps in bash history](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-history-display-date-time/)

Why this doesn't give me the complete history?

See the answer of [@michael-homer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/73093/michael-homer)

> If you want to make sure that they're always written immediately, you can put that command into your PROMPT_COMMAND variable:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```