# How to export Linux command history to a file with the command logs

Tags: ssh, command-line, command-history

I need to export all commands and the commands' log of a user in a Linux distribution like Debian.
Any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [History with bash file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384956/history-with-bash-file)

Comment: Depends what you mean by all commands, and what you mean by Linux. Linux is the kernel. This name is often used in error to mean the whole system Gnu/Linux plus the rest. Is your question: How do I save, to a file, all of the command that a user runs in the shell (bash)? Also does it have to be secure? (prevent the user from deleting entries)?

Comment: It's absolutely not clear what you're after, but try using the `script` command; you will have in typescript both the commands you entered and their output.

Comment: Yes, thank you all.